# Deserialize JSON value

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

Scenario :  Deserialize the JSON format data using wrapper class.
 I have JSON data and wrapper class for the JSON. I want to see value for one of the property in inner class of the wrapper class. But I cannot able to access the inner class in my batch class. Below are the sample wrapper class and batch class

Wrapper class :

```
Public class JSON2ApexWrapperClass{

    public class Aliases
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comments
    {
        public string countat { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
     public static JSON2ApexWrapperClass parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2ApexWrapperClass) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2ApexWrapperClass.class);
    }
}
```

Batch Class :

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
    string jsonResult = 'body of json';
    JSON2ApexWrapperClass jsonDeserialize = JSON2ApexWrapperClass.parse(jsonResult);
    system.debug('*******  Deserialized  *********'+jsonDeserialize);
    system.debug('*******  Deserialized  *********'+jsonDeserialize.Comments); //I CANNOT ABLE TO ACCESS COMMENTS CLASS

}
```

sample JSON string :

```
{
   "@count":"1",
   "@querycount":"1",
   "@ranking":"adaptive",
   "mindTouchPage":{
      "id":"333",
      "guid":"01955249d38a4c8681940f8e84b55b90",
      "draftstate":"inactive",
      "href":"https://sampleTest.us/@api/poki/pages/333?redirects=0",
      "deleted":"false",
      "@unpublish":"true",
      "@revision":"2",
      "@score":"1",
      "aliases":{
         "href":"https://sampleTest.us/@api/poki/pages/333/aliases"
      },
      "comments":{
         "@count":"0",
         "href":"https://sampleTest.us/@api/poki/pages/333/comments"
      }  
   }
}
```

**How to access inner class in batch class and how to see the deserialized values of comments class**.

Comment: Can you please post a sample JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Access inner class

So if you want to access inner class variable then try something

```
JSON2ApexWrapperClass.Aliases objAliases = new JSON2ApexWrapperClass.Aliases();
system.debug(objAliases.href);//get href value

JSON2ApexWrapperClass.Comments objComments = new JSON2ApexWrapperClass.Comments();
system.debug(objComments.countat);//get href value
system.debug(objComments.href);//get href value
```

### Updates

As per your JSON structure you can't create use apex class for deserialize the JSON because json code contains the @ in variable name

So you need to go with `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`

```
String myvar = '{'+
'   "@count":"1",'+
'   "@querycount":"1",'+
'   "@ranking":"adaptive",'+
'   "mindTouchPage":{'+
'      "id":"333",'+
'      "guid":"01955249d38a4c8681940f8e84b55b90",'+
'      "draftstate":"inactive",'+
'      "href":"https://sampleTest.us/@api/poki/pages/333?redirects=0",'+
'      "deleted":"false",'+
'      "@unpublish":"true",'+
'      "@revision":"2",'+
'      "@score":"1",'+
'      "aliases":{'+
'         "href":"https://sampleTest.us/@api/poki/pages/333/aliases"'+
'      },'+
'      "comments":{'+
'         "@count":"0",'+
'         "href":"https://sampleTest.us/@api/poki/pages/333/comments"'+
'      }  '+
'   }'+
'}';

map<String, object> mapJSON = (map<String, object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(myvar);

map<String, object> mapJSON1 = (map<String, object>)mapJSON.get('mindTouchPage');

map<String, object>  mapAliases = (map<String, object>)mapJSON1.get('aliases');
map<String, object>  mapComments = (map<String, object>)mapJSON1.get('comments');

 //get the alias href value
system.debug(mapAliases.get('href'));
//get the comment @count value
system.debug(mapComments.get('@count'));
 //get the comment href value
system.debug(mapComments.get('href'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have deserialized json format like above but when am seeing in debug the value is coming as null. Any workaround needs to get the value?

Comment: @sfdcDev if you are not getting the parsing error then may be you are getting null value from your jason iteself

Comment: there is value existing for href, countat in JSON but it is comingas null when deserializing

Comment: @sfdcDev can you pls share your JSON (pls add in your question) ?

Comment: updated question with json

Comment: @sfdcDev you can't use JSON.serialize here because your json contain the @ in variable name(this will give compile time error).. SO i have added solution with  `JSON.deserializeUntyped(myvar);` check my updated answer and let me know if that make sense. if you are not aware of `JSON.deserializeUntyped(myvar);` pls check the documentation . Thanks!

Comment: I have replaced those special character variables using JSON.Replace method and changed wrapper class properties name accordingly but still the value is coming as null after deserialization.

Comment: @sfdcDev can you try with my solution once ?

Comment: I have already tried untyped deserialization with map it is fetching value

Comment: @sfdcDev cool then I guess your issue now resolved